# Find sequences of minimum 3 values that differ only by 0.5%

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-itertools

lets say I have a list like `[1,2,1.5,2,1.99,2.01,4]` and I want my function to find the sequence `[2,1.99,2.01]` and build a new list of it. This can happen multiple times while looping over the initial list. I hope my problem is understandable.

Thanks in advance

This is my attempt:

```
import itertools
Support = []

Liste1 = [1,2,1.5,2,1.99,2.01,4]
Liste2 = Liste1[1:]
Liste1.pop(-1)

for S1,S2 in itertools.zip_longest(Liste1, Liste2):
    if S2<=1.05*S1 and S2>=0.95*S1:
        Support.append(S1)
```

The problem is that this loop will compare the value to the value before and not to the first value which was detected as the start of a series.

Comment: Can you share with us where do you get stuck in your attempts?

Comment: to be honest i do not have any idea how to takle this problem.

Comment: Still looking for a solution?

Comment: found a good workaround, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Layer1 = [round(x,2) for x in list(data["Close"])]
            Layer2 = Layer1[0:1]
            Layer1.pop(0)

            Layer3 = []
            Layer4 = []


            for element in Layer1:
                if element < 1.01*Layer2[0] and element > 0.99*Layer2[0]:
                    Layer2.append(element)
                    if len(Layer2)>= 6:
                        Layer3.extend(Layer2)
                        Layer4.append(statistics.mean(Layer3))
                        Layer3.clear()
                        Layer2.clear()
                        Layer2.append(element)
                else:
                    Layer2.clear()
                    Layer2.append(element)

            R_S = sorted([round(s,2) for s in Layer4])
            R_S_clean = R_S[0:1]
            R_S.pop(0)

            for element in R_S:
                if element >= 1.01*R_S_clean[-1] or element <= 0.99*R_S_clean[-1]:
                    R_S_clean.append(element)

            R_S_clean_rev = reversed(R_S_clean)

            for element in R_S_clean_rev:
                if element < Price:
                    Support = element
                    Delta_S = str(abs(round((100-((100/element)*Price)),2))) + "%"
                    break
                else:
                    Support = "/"
                    Delta_S = "/"

            for element in R_S_clean:
                if element > Price:
                    Resistance = element
                    Delta_R = str(abs(round((100-((100/element)*Price)),2))) + "%"
                    break
                else:
                    Resistance = "/"
                    Delta_R = "/"
```

This is my workaround, time will tell if the performance is good enough.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).